# FFmpeg format error when using alphaextract

Tags: ffmpeg, mask, alpha

I'm trying to mask an image using a png circle

When I use `alphaextract`, I get this error:
`The following filters could not choose their formats: Parsed_alphaextract_X`

Here's my command:

```sh
ffmpeg -i "https://i.imgur.com/aZkbbWn.jpeg" -i "https://i.imgur.com/jVNCqIj.png"  -filter_complex "[0]scale=200:200[ava];[1]scale=200:200,alphaextract[alfa];[ava][alfa]alphamerge" circle_ava.png
```

I tried adding `format=yuv420p,` to input `[1]` but it didn't help

I also tried adding `-pix_fmt yuv420p` as the first parameter, but no luck

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with `format=rgba`

```sh
ffmpeg -i "https://i.imgur.com/aZkbbWn.jpeg" -i "https://i.imgur.com/jVNCqIj.png" -filter_complex "[0]scale=200:200[ava];[1]scale=200:200,format=rgba,alphaextract[alfa];[ava][alfa]alphamerge" circle_ava.png
```